# Error creating bean with name 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, pom.xml

I am learning how to use Spring Boot. I am trying to connect my application with my database, but I am not entirely sure why I am getting this error and how to fix it. I can't find anything online. Please help me. If you need more information, please ask me and I will do everything I can.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <groupId>com.notes</groupId>
    <artifactId>notes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>notes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties, I do not know why but every propery except server.port is grayed out:

```
#GENERAL
server.port = 8080
#
#DATABASE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/note_application
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#JPA/Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#Transactions
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

Full error stack trace when running spring-boot:run

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.2.0:run (default-cli) @ notes ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)
2023-11-28T13:01:56.786-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.notes.notes.NotesApplication         : Starting NotesApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 with PID 15356 (C:\Users\tobia\Documents\_proyectos\Java\notes\target\classes started by tobia in C:\Users\tobia\Documents\_proyectos\Java\notes)
2023-11-28T13:01:56.793-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.notes.notes.NotesApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-28T13:01:57.391-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-28T13:01:57.412-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-28T13:01:57.960-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2023-11-28T13:01:57.969-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-11-28T13:01:57.970-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-11-28T13:01:58.037-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-11-28T13:01:58.038-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1202 ms
2023-11-28T13:01:58.199-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-28T13:01:58.265-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2023-11-28T13:01:58.301-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2023-11-28T13:01:58.567-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-11-28T13:01:58.596-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-28T13:01:58.762-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6b2aafbc
2023-11-28T13:01:58.763-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-28T13:01:58.806-03:00  WARN 15356 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000511: The 5.5.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 5.7.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions.
2023-11-28T13:01:58.810-03:00  WARN 15356 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2023-11-28T13:01:59.640-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-11-28T13:01:59.687-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-28T13:01:59.774-03:00  WARN 15356 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-11-28T13:01:59.800-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2023-11-28T13:02:00.013-03:00  WARN 15356 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers]: Factory method 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' threw exception with message: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
2023-11-28T13:02:00.014-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-28T13:02:00.016-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-11-28T13:02:00.023-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-11-28T13:02:00.024-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-11-28T13:02:00.035-03:00  INFO 15356 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-28T13:02:00.052-03:00 ERROR 15356 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers]: Factory method 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' threw exception with message: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:643) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.notes.notes.NotesApplication.main(NotesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers]: Factory method 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' threw exception with message: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1243) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:517) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(ResolvableType.java:368) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(ResolvableType.java:282) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:155) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:147) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:883) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:842) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1650) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1468) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1390) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2196) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2190) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.platformTransactionManagerCustomizers(TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.java:44) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I am following this tutorial (it is in spanish): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vHzVN0EiQc
I am stuck at minute 2:23

When I know the real error cause, I will update the title to help anyone with the same problem :)

I tried adding this lines to application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#JPA/Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#Transactions
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

I also checked that the Resources folder was properly marked (and it is).

Comment: Hey, I just wrote an answer about the problem and about the solution that was able to help you. Please consider it as a starting point for every project that you are going to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed the problem was in autoconfigution but you will have some miss configuration on `spring-boot` because of version's that you are going to use.

Here you have to change

the version from `2.6.3`

Something like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Because the version of parent in your case is `3.2.0`

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

And also the best way in my opinion is Do NOT define the dependency versions in `pom.xml` if that dependency is managed by Spring.

It mean you have to remove all
`version` tag where `groupId` is next one

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
```

Also as I mentioned above don’t mix the framework version here is why you should avoid it [Changes from 2.x to 3.x](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it! By using IntelliJ Idea, I've found the dependency containing the **"platformTransactionManagerCustomizers"** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```